# OracleDataAdapter not filling DataTable when querying to a DBLink

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to execute a query from OracleDataAdapter in C#, this query will go to a DBLink available in the DB, but for some reason when it needs to fill the datatable it throws me an error:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException - ndex was outside the bounds of the array
```

the code I'm trying to execute is:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select count(*) alive from dual@MYDBLINK");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = conn;
using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
{
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet); //Here is where it fails
}
```

The query works if I execute in sql developer, and the code works if I remove the DBLink information and let the query as `select count(*) alive from dual`, so I asume, that the issue here is something with the DBLink or the @ character.

Comment: do you connect in sql developer and code using same credentials? I bet ya - not. I never heard about syntax like "from dual@something". `Dual` is synonym and doesn't have any trails. Besides, for this - just do `ExecuteScalar`. Why do you need all this coding?

Comment: Hello I'm developing a dashboard that allows the user to check if certains DB Links are working, so I query to dual of the DB Link only to know that is returning something..
And yes I'm connecting to the DB with the same credentials, also if I execute the code with other query (without DB Link connections) it works and returns  values.